# WebClient.DownloadFile(Address, FileName) Dúvida usando variável

Tags: c#, atualização, webclient

Bom, estou criando um sistema de atualização, e está dando erro em uma parte

```
WebClient web = new WebClient();
string DownloadVersion = web.DownloadString("https://drive.google.com/uc?authuser=0&id=1bpVdsyUj3oOn1gLbcVRE7uZjIczI5Yc_&export=download");
string UltimaVersao = DownloadVersion.Split('\n')[0];
string VersaoDessePrograma = Application.ProductVersion; 

if (Convert.ToDecimal(VersaoDessePrograma) < Convert.ToDecimal(UltimaVersao))
{
    if (MessageBox.Show("Um novo update está disponivel!" + Environment.NewLine + "Você quer atualizar?", "Atualização", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo, MessageBoxIcon.Question) == DialogResult.Yes) 
    {
        web.DownloadFile(DownloadVersion.Split('\n')[1], "Algoritmos 1.0.1.exe");
        MessageBox.Show("O programa foi baixado!" + Environment.NewLine + "O aplicativo será fechado.", "Atualização", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information); 
        System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(Application.StartupPath + @"\Algoritmos 1.0.1.exe");
        Close();
    }
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("O programa já está atualizado!", "Verificador", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
```

Esse erro é o seguinte, quando eu coloco na linha `web.DownloadFile` na parte do fileName o seguinte código: `Algoritmos 1.0.1.exe` dá certo, normalmente. Mas quando eu utilizo a variável da última versão: `Algoritmos " + UltimaVersao + ".exe`, lança um erro.

Vai a imagem utilizando o código `Algoritmos 1.0.1.exe`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Vai a imagem utilizando o código `Algoritmos " + UltimaVersao + ".exe`:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Por que acontece esse erro? Como resolver? Podem me ajudar? Grato!

Comment: Onde UltimaVersao = "1.0.1"

Comment: Lucas tem certeza que UltimaVersao não foi alterado? Tente usar um `MessageBox.Show(UltimaVersao);` ou `Console.Write(UltimaVersao)` pra ter certeza que o valor dessa variavel não tem caracteres como quebras de linha, tabulações, nulos ou outros sinais como `:` e `?`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Provavelmente isto:

```
 string UltimaVersao = DownloadVersion.Split('\n')[0];
```

Esta retornando algo que você não imagina, você provavelmente espera por algo como `1.0.1`, mas talvez isto esteja retornando qualquer outra coisa, se fiz simplesmente isto:

```
MessageBox.Show(UltimaVersao);
```

ou

```
Console.Write(UltimaVersao);
```

Você verá que provavelmente deve haver caracteres não válidos, como:

- Quebra de linhas (\n)
- Retorno (`\r`)
- Tabulação (`\t`)
- Nulo (`\0`)
- outros como não aceitos como: `?` e `:`

Pois para criar arquivos nas pastas alguns caracteres não são permitidos, o que ocasionará o erro:

> ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.

Se parecer no `MessageBox.show` que esta "normal", algo como `1.0.1` então é porque deve ter alguma quebra de linha, pode experimentar remover todos com replace:

```
UltimaVersao = UltimaVersao.Replace(System.Environment.NewLine, "");
```

Ou então usar o [`.Trim`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t97s7bs3(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
UltimaVersao = UltimaVersao.Trim();
```

Mas se tiver receio de ter mais caracteres inválidos você pode usar [**`Path.GetInvalidPathChars();`**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getinvalidfilenamechars(v=vs.110).aspx) para limpar os caracteres inválidos